# Home page seems to be broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, status-norepro

Looks like the home page i.e. "Top Questions" is currently broken!

[image: Home page error]

Comment: Can't repro this one. Looks fine to me.

Comment: @Snow yep seems to be fine now.

Comment: I also see no issue...

Comment: I thought it was an improvement :-)

Comment: How do we get HNQ to be broken?